# IOS - Back Button IOS6 vs IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I add a space between the background image of the Navigation and the Text in IOS 7.  For IOS 6, adding a space make the text at the correct place.

Navbar from IOS 6 :

[image: Navbar from IOS 6 :]

Navbar from IOS 7 :

[image: Navbar from IOS 7 :]

My code in AppDelegate to redefine all back buttons :

```
// Change the appearance of other navigation button
UIImage *barButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back_str.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 31, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//Adapt the Text of the Buttons
NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:20.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In my code, to set the text :

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
self.navigationItem.title =  @" Zurück";
}
```

How can Add this space in IOs 7. Thanks.

Comment: simply it will be [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back_str.png"]]; you can make a check for ios 7.0.

Comment: You can always bake the space into the image itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(5, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thank's, It works ! 
I also suppressed the space I added for IOS 6.